# Error when trying to run a docker images with Docker Enterprise in Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I recently installed Docker Enterprise on my Windows Server 2016 machine.

However, when I try to do a docker run hello-world, I get this error

> docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the
>   manifest list entries.

I think it may be because it's not in experimental mode, but doing the `dockerd --experimental` command causes it to hang.